# How to load Bose-Einstein Condensates into an optical lattice?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, cold-atoms

In cold atom experiments, what techniques are used to load Bose-Einstein Condensates into an optical lattice??

Comment: Have you read this paper?  http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0206063

Answer (score 0):

An atomic ensemble has to be trapped somewhere before cooling to degeneracy (BEC or Fermi degenerate). Loading into an optical lattice is simply turning on an optical lattice (retroreflected light) that overlaps with the original trap, then turning off the original trap.

Answer (score -1):

(Short answer) In cold atom, the laser cooling might do the trick, where the magnetic fields(potential) were used to trap the atoms, i.e. "magneto-optical trap".

In ultra cold atom, the evaporative cooling was needed to be applied.

(Long answer) The professors might explain it thoroughly.